# Prevent Line Break Before Long Wrapping Words

Tags: css

I have long strings of text that is inside paragraphs. The strings don't have spaces and can be broken at any point. I'd like the strings to wrap instead of overflowing so I'm currently using `span{overflow-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-word}`. This works for most of my needs but causes the data to start on a new line before wrapping.

```
 <p>My paragraph <span>.---.--.-----.-</span> is like this.</p>
```

Is there a way to disable a line break before long "words"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at `word-break: break-all;` option as well? It will break the long words at any character. It would create a nice paragraph but the words are being split at random parts.

You could try to use it like:

```
p {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```